# Self answer and research effort

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I recently wrote a self-answered question to help others who might have the same question I did. In the process of writing the question, I found that I had to essentially make it look like I had done almost no research (anyone who had done research could probably have found the answer themselves).

It is okay to write a question that shows very little research effort when I am writing a self answer?

Comment: _Who_ plans on answering the question should not change the quality requirements of a post. Then again, there are tons of highly upvoted, no research  questions all over SE, so, while that makes sense in theory, it isn't heavily practiced.

Comment: @CarrieKendall I would avoid answering questions in the comments. If that is your position, post an answer. For the record, I agree with you.

Comment: That isn't an answer, it's an observation :)

Comment: research isn't required, but lack of research is a downvote reason, so don't be surprised if you receive downvotes on a question that doesn't show research.

Comment: Between the comment-answers-in-denial on this question and the actual answers on the proposed duplicate, I believe my question is answered.